# Doing a SELECT * from TABLE gives "Cannot read field 'records' of type INT64 as UINT64"

Tags: google-bigquery

I am running into something that appears to be a global BigQuery issue that started maybe only a few days ago. It was definitely working on Jan 7th 2019. I narrowed down the issue to a simple `SELECT * FROM TABLE` which throws a `Cannot read field 'records' of type INT64 as UINT64`. The `records` field is declared as `INTEGER` in the schema and the table is a result of an aggregate query.

I am getting the same error both programmatically as well as in BigQuery UI.

If I explicitly list STRING fields, the query works. As soon as I reference `records` which is INTEGER, the query fails.

Job id is `dulcet-outlook-94110:US.bquxjob_5883645e_16858aba0ae`.

Alternatively, everyone can reproduce this using public data by saving the following query into a `temp` table and then doing a simple `SELECT * from temp`.

```
SELECT state, count(*) cnt FROM [bigquery-public-data:samples.natality]
group by state
```

This gives a slightly different but essentially the same error: `Type mismatch for column 'cnt' in table temp. Expected type 'uint64', actual type 'int64' in file :mdb=cloud-dataengine`.

(**EDIT**: Make sure to use "**Allow Large Results**" otherwise it will work fine).

Comment: I can reproduce the error - all the provided steps work for me. Please report on the issue tracker, and add job ids so the team can go deeper into this

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation (maybe post it as an answer too?). I have created an issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122988145. I hope it gets resolved soon. It's affecting our product badly.

Comment: Please add a job id. No job id makes it very hard to debug

Comment: Job id is already in SO question and the issue links to it. Also, this is so easy to reproduce.

Comment: It's not easy to reproduce: I could not reproduce. Please include job id on issue request, so the team can help you. Just trying to be helpful here, but you can choose to ignore.

Comment: And I thank you so much. But please note that my failing job id was included right form the start. So even if the problem is not easy to reproduce (even though your very first comment indicated that you succeeded), the existing job id should provide enough to debug.

Comment: Same as Felipe. I **can't** reproduce this error. Tried both legacy-SQL and standard-SQL. https://gist.github.com/polleyg/df408183273e382d969123c5c1a034fd

Comment: Please make sure "Allow Large Results" is ON when running the first query. Without it even I can't reproduce it. I did not know this was relevant. Edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for raising this up. This is indeed a bug in BigQuery, a fix has been completely rolled out now.

For the broken tables, although data is not lost, they have an inconsistent state with the schema. So please try to regenerate them if you can, as for now their schemas won't automatically fix themselves yet. We are working on ways to fix the schema of the existing affected tables, but it might take some time.

If you still have any problem feel free to report to the public issue tracker `wpfwannabe` created above.